# Issue in Fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

When I click on the back icon in the layout then it goes to previous fragment but it doesn't go to the fragment it was killed. what is the solution for this?
I'm using `finish()` and backstack but it not works for me

```
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                android.support.v4.app.Fragment onlineFragments = new OnlineFragments();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManagerprofile = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentprofileTransaction = fragmentManagerprofile.beginTransaction();
                fragmentprofileTransaction.replace(R.id.background_fragment, onlineFragments);
                fragmentprofileTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Fragment A

```
        case R.id.recharge:
            HomeActvity.toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment Recharge = new Prepaid_recharge();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, Recharge);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
```

Comment: It goes to previous fragment but do not go to killed fragment? More clarity please

Comment: means it goes to home screen in phone like we using finish()

Comment: Fragment A Clicks then Fragment B Opens.When i am click on Fragment B it goes to Fragment A, This is how it should work na? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: when i click on Fragment A fragment b opens in fragment b layout toolbar has back icon so when i click on back icon it goes to fragment A

Comment: That means you dont want fragment A to open when you press back in fraagment B? Then wat should happen if you click back?

Comment: Could you please also paste your code by which you opened fragment B from Fragment A? @A.asha

Comment: see edited question

Comment: If you want to go to device Home screen directly from fragment B. I would suggest you to use "getActivity().finish()" instead of above code inside back button click listener.

Comment: in my layout i have one back icon when i am click on icon it will go to previous fragment thats what i want.getactivity().finish() is not working like reqquirement

Comment: You have two different container id's in both fragments inside replace function.Are you using two different activities and containers for both fragments? Because if you are using same activity for both then container id should be same for both. @A.asha

Answer (score 2):

Whenever your making Transactions between fragments and you want to navigate back to the previous fragment(s) (Back Button), in the transaction, you must add this transaction to the backStack before committing:

***Android docs:***

"Before you call commit(), however, you might want to call ***addToBackStack()***, in order to add the transaction to a back stack of fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and ***allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back button.***"

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to add and remove the fragment. In case I do not need that fragment to be in the back stack I send the boolean value as false. Doing this when pressing back button from toolbar It open the correct activity

```
public static void changeFragment (MyActivity activity, Fragment fragment, int fragmentContainer, boolean addToBackStack){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainer, fragment);

      /*here we keep track of fragments and avoiding last blank fragment by passing true*/
        if(addToBackStack){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```